# What is the difference between rand's Sample and IndependentSample traits?

Tags: random, rust

The [`rand`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rand/rand/index.html) crate has a [`Sample`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rand/rand/distributions/trait.Sample.html) trait and an [`IndependentSample`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rand/rand/distributions/trait.IndependentSample.html) trait.

Obviously, "Independent" is the difference between the two, but what does this mean semantically in the numbers generated? In the non-independent case, how are samples possibly dependent on one another?

Comment: Can you expand on what you don't understand from [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rand/rand/distributions/trait.IndependentSample.html)? *Samples that do not require keeping track of state. Since no state is recorded, each sample is (statistically) independent of all others, assuming the `Rng` used has this property.* Have you read [the Wikipedia page on "independence"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory))?

Answer (score 2):

The only difference between these two traits is that `Sample` takes a `&mut self` whereas `IndependentSample` takes a `&self`.
This means that `Sample` could store a state, but not `IndependentSample`.

The naming choice is described in `IndependentSample` documentation:

> Since no state is recorded, each sample is (statistically) independent of all others, assuming the `Rng` used has this property.